# How many books were decided at the Council of Rome 382, Council of Carthage 397 and the Synod of Hippo 393? Was it all 73 books of the Catholic canon?

Tags: canon, deuterocanonical-books

How many books were decided at the Council of Rome 382, Council of Carthage 397 and the Synod of Hippo 393?

Were exactly all 73 books of the Catholic Bible declared canon at these three councils?

[Catholic.com](https://www.catholic.com/qa/was-the-canon-of-scripture-determined-before-the-church-councils-that-decided-it) says:

> It was not until the Synod of Rome under Pope Damasus in A.D. 382, followed by the Councils of Hippo and Carthage, that the Catholic Church defined, albeit non-infallibly, which books made it into the New Testament and which didn’t.

I didn't see the word "Baruch" on either of the Wikipedia pages for the two later councils:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synod_of_Hippo

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Councils_of_Carthage

Wikipedia says Baruch was missing from the Council of Rome:

> The Council of Rome was a meeting of Catholic Church officials and theologians which took place in AD 382 under the authority of Pope Damasus I, the then Bishop of Rome. According to Decretum Gelasianum, which is a work written by an anonymous scholar between AD 519 and 553, the Council of Rome cites a list of books of scripture presented as having been made canonical. This list mentions all the deuterocanonical books except Baruch and the Letter of Jeremiah as a part of the Old Testament Canon.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Rome

Comment: Notice that two of these councils don't explicitly mention Lamentations either, the reason being that it was considered part of Jeremiah; same for Baruch and the Epistle.

Comment: @Lucian Thanks! If Baruch is considered part of Jeremiah, does that mean Wikipedia is misleading? From Wikipedia it sounds like Baruch is missing. Instead, if what you say is true, the mention of Baruch is explicitly mentioned because it's implicitly part of Jeremiah

Comment: I never said it is, merely that it might be; personally, I can't exactly guess what went through the minds of people living thousands of years ago, and thousands of miles away; all I wanted to point out was that one should be very careful, in such ambiguous instances, how one interprets such vague statements; Ruth, for instance, was also traditionally considered part of Judges; its lack of explicit mention in some canonical lists implies nothing.

Comment: @Lucian Thanks! What does "it" refer to here: "I never said it is, merely that it might be"

Comment: Whether the two synods implied Baruch and/or the Epistle, apart from Lamentations, when stating Jeremiah.

Comment: @Lucian Ah, okay, makes sense! Thank you; I misunderstood!